# How to create a randomized search query for a discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, google-image-search

I want to make a bot command that allows the user to get a random image of their choice. (!image dog)

How do I let the user input the image that they want to be searched? This is what I have so far:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case "dog":
            image(message);

            break;
    }
});

function image(message) {
    var options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + "dog",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome",
        },
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, responseBody) {
        if (error) {
            return;
        }

        $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

        var links = $(".image a.link");

        var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));

        console.log(urls);
        if (!urls.length) {
            return;
        }

        // Send result
        message.channel.send(urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you mean by "input the image that they want to be searched"? Are you saying that instead of just doing `!image dog`, you want your users to be able to do `!image cat` and get cat pictures? Or are you saying that they should be able to do something like `!image dog poodle` and get image results for a specific dog?

Comment: the first one, i want users to be able to search for what they want

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is on the right track to doing what you want. You simply need to properly use your `args` variable.

**The Problem(s)**

First of all, you need to separate your `args` from your command. The code you provided in your question currently counts the command itself ("image") as the first arg and "dog" as the second arg, whereas "dog" is supposed to be the first argument of the command. So we need to separate the command from the args, and we can do so easily with `Array.shift()` which removes the first element of an array and returns it.

In your current code, you have a `switch` statement that checks the value of the first arg in the message (`args[0]`), and if the first arg is "dog", you are searching for dog images. But what you want to do is you want to be able to search for more than just dogs, for whatever image the user wants. That means you'll first need to get rid of the argument-checking `switch`, because as it is now it will only allow users to search for "dog".

Next, you need to realize that you want to search for an image of whatever the user puts in. So what's the value that the user is putting in? It's contained in `args[0]`. So if you want to be able to search for whatever `args[0]` is, instead of doing `"http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + "dog"` you need to instead do `"http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + args[0]`. In order to do that, you'll also need to give your `image` method access to `args[0]`, which you can do by passing it in as an argument of the method.

**The Solution**

So here's how these simple fixes will look in your code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let command = args.shift(); //separates and removes command from args

    switch (command) {
        case "image":
            image(message, args[0]);

            break;
    }
});

function image(message, query) {
    //'query' now represents 'args[0]'

    var options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome",
        },
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, responseBody) {
        if (error) {
            return;
        }

        $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

        var links = $(".image a.link");

        var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));

        console.log(urls);
        if (!urls.length) {
            return;
        }

        // Send result
        message.channel.send(urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
    });
}
```

However, note that this will only take the first argument and search for it (it will not include spaces). So if you did `!image furry cats`, it would only look up images of "furry" and not "furry cats". If you want to account for spaces, then use all of the args instead of just `args[0]`. You could do so by replacing all occurrences of `args[0]` in this code with `args.join(" ")`.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question. This answer is solely based off of the somewhat limited information you provided in your question and comment.

Comment: Thank you, it works! sorry if i was confusing, im new to this!

Comment: No problem! When it comes to your question, you did very well by providing all of the necessary code for your problem, and stating your question. You also properly clarified in your comment. Just be sure to be more specific when asking questions like these in the future, as there is always more than one way to interpret a general question!